# remix.ethereum.org Crashes and Gas consume

Tags: solidity, remix, out-of-gas

I'm new on Blockchain. I'm trying make a simple NFT Collection of random SVG.

I got the Random part covered.

My question is about the math within a contract and Gas consume, to be more specific, 'for loops':

Every time I try to make a 'for loop' to generate an SVG path, my Ethereum Remix crashes, I believe it is related to the consumption of Gas,
but I don't understand much, can anyone explain to me? :D

I also use Visual Studio Code, but I have the same problem with Gas and Transaction Failed.

Here is the idea of my contract:

```
    constructor() ERC721("vjkNFT", "vjkNFT") { 
        
                lines = 6;
                colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black", "orange"];
                backgrounds = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black", "orange"];
    }

    function generateRandomNumber( ) public view returns (uint256 uintRandomNumber) {
        retuns Random Number
    }

    function generateSVG() public view returns (string memory svg) {
        svg = "<svg version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 100 100'";
        svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'"));
        string memory background = backgrounds[(generateRandomNumber() * 2 ) % backgrounds.length];
        svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "style='background-color: ",background," '>"));

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            uint256 randomNumber = generateRandomNumber() + i;            
            string memory color = colors[randomNumber % colors.length];
            svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "<line stroke='" , color , "' "));
            svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "stroke-width='4' ")); // I'll add randomness in the positions later
            svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "opacity='0.3' "));
            svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "x1='50' "));
            svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "x2='150' />"));
        }

        svg = string(abi.encodePacked(svg, "</svg>"));
    }
```

Comment: I tried the code and it works, it is a bit slow, but it works. Possible problems using strings is expensive, using too much memory is also expensive. The code generated by solidity isn't optimal for string manipulation.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.. I`m happy.. Now that I know it kind of works, I'll try to improve, and study what you said: "The code generated by solidity isn't optimal for string manipulation"